# Running electron app with asar on linux /Cannot GET index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, electron-packager

I have built an electron app with asar bundle under /app/resources/app.asar. When I run this app in linux I see application doesn't launch and it throws **/Cannot GET index.html**.

This application is built to serve angular distro by nodejs server running inside electron framework.

This is how app is built in packge.json

```
 "builderForLinx1": "electron-packager --out linx64 --overwrite --platform linux --appname myApp .  --executable-name ClientSettings --asar"
```

This is main.js calling app.js(nodejs entry)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const serverJS = require('./app');//node server

let win;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webviewTag: true
    },
    show:false
  })

  
  win.loadURL("http://localhost:4440/index.html");
  win.setMenuBarVisibility(false);

  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })

  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show();
    win.maximize();
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

```
**app.js**
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
const routes = require('./server/index.route');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let port = 4440;
app.set('port', port);
let server;
server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.on('error', onError);

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'?'pipe ' + addr: 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
  }
server.listen(port);


app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/Angular-electron')))

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made from homepage
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'?'Pipe ' + port:'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}


routes(app);
module.exports = app;
```

But if I build the app without -asar the app launches as expected! I do asar just to reduce the filecontent. This is part of the requirement.

Comment: I have a doubt can I asar electron app in linux, has anyone done this before?Any help or suggestion on this is greatly appreciated.